# (Java) Cannot instantiate the type image?

Tags: java, object, graphics, superclass

Here is my code:

```
package Main;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gamestart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Image i = new Image();

    }

}
```

It gives me an error. I know that this is supposed to happen when it's an abstract class, but it's not abstract,and the superclass is just `java.lang.Object`. Does anyone know why this is happening?

EDIT:
Okay, i learned that java.awt.image is abstract, but still, how come it still gives me an error?

Comment: `java.awt.Image` *is* an abstract class.

Comment: You will want to take a look at [Working with Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/), in particular, look for `BufferedImage`

Comment: `"Okay, i learned that java.awt.image is abstract, but still, how come it still gives me an error?"` -- um,... maybe because it **is** abstract, as you now admit to see. So why should this confuse you?

Answer (score 7):

> I know that this is supposed to happen when it's an abstract class,
>   but it's not abstract

see [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html):

```
public abstract class Image
extends Object
```

> The **abstract class** Image is the superclass of all classes that
>   represent graphical images. The image must be obtained in a
>   platform-specific manner.